# Get No. of approvals on a pull request using github's graphql api

Tags: javascript, github, graphql

I'm trying to get the number of approvals a pull request has received. I can get the number of *reviews*, but that includes all reviews whether approved, rejected, comments etc.

````
```
{
  search(query: "type:pr state:open involves:${username}", type: ISSUE, first: 10) {
      edges {
      node {
        ... on PullRequest {
          reviews {
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

```
````

is there a way to get just the approvals?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to look at the `state` field of a review to see if it was approved. Seems like it would be pretty easy to just loop though each review and count the approvals that way.

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request

Comment: This seems like it's exactly what I was looking for. I'm already searching on the state of the pull request, but I never thought to look at the state of the review.

Answer (score 0):

For receiving only the approvals, we can use the the `state` argument and pass in `APPROVED`. To get the total count, GitHub can return this without the need to loop through results. Simply ask for `totalCount`.

Here's a simple working snippet:

```
{
  repository (owner: "YOUR_ORG" name: "YOUR_REPO_NAME") {
    pullRequests (first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          reviews (first: 100 states: APPROVED) {
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```